# Could you describe the Soufflé technique?

Tags: eggs

Could you describe the Soufflé technique? What pitfalls should you avoid?

Comment: Welcome, Gui Junkie. Your question is a little general. Can you tighten it up a bit? I assume you mean "how do you cook them" and not more general experiences like "I fell in love over one in Paris" or "I found out about the affair while making a chocolate soufflé." ;o)

Comment: Community wiki about souffle?

Comment: @GUI: I suggest splitting those questions up into multiple questions. The "what ingredients should be used" one is off-topic though, due to it being a recipe request.

Comment: May I recommend Hello World Souffle http://www.dangermouse.net/esoteric/chef_hello.html

Comment: Hello World Souffle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The key to any Soufflé is the egg whites.  The air bubbles trapped inside of them is what causes the mixture to rise.  (As daniel mentions McGee puts it at somewhere like 25% due to the air expanding from the heat and 75% from the steam interacting with the bubbles.)

Problems occur because the Soufflé is so reliant on steam and the egg whites setting.  If the base dilutes the egg whites then they can't set properly and the bubbles trapped inside of them can't do their job of making it rise.  If the whites are just mixed into the base thoughtlessly most of the foam will be destroyed.

Most recipes agree that stiff but moist and glossy peaks are how the egg whites should be beaten.

Answer (score 3):

All souffles will fall. Anyone who tells you otherwise is selling something. Souffles rise because of the action of steam within them (I don't have my copy on loan, but this is discussed in some detail in McGee, 2004 edition). Popping them back in the oven briefly will resuscitate them enough to take to the table, if they have fallen too quickly.

Answer (score 2):

Souffle technique? Basically, make a bechamel sauce, whisk in egg yolks, stir in seasonings, flavors or foods, fold in stiff beaten egg whites. Put into a prepared souffle dish (greased and coated with any number of different items... depending if you are making savory or sweet souffle). Bake in the center of the oven.

Comment: Sounds easy enough. Oven temp?

Comment: Length of baking time depends a lot on souffle size. My cheese souffle, which serves 6, cooks for 30 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Souffl%C3%A9)

About 15min in a 190ºC (375°F) oven. I'll ask a separate question about the convection oven.

Comment: Follow your recipe. Sweet souffles tend to be more "gooey" and creamy in the center (and cook for less time), and savory tend to be a bit "drier" (and cook a bit longer).