# Can you use a convection oven to make a Soufflé?

Tags: baking, eggs, oven, souffle, convection

I separated this question from the [original](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/6295/could-you-describe-the-souffle-technique) as there were no answers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can. In professional kitchens, virtually all ovens are convection, and they work just fine. You may need to reduce the heat about 25 degrees.

Comment: I lower by 25 degrees (F) with all recipes when I convert to convection.  Should I not do it with some?

Comment: @justkt, you'll need to use your judgement. When roasting a chicken breast, probably no problems without reducing temperature. With something more finicky, you will need to reduce.

Answer (score 0):

My Kitchenaid combination oven has a soufflé setting!

Comment: Have you made a soufflé in it? Manufacturers write all sorts of things on their products; it doesn't always mean that they're well-suited to the task.