# Troubleshooting a soufflé that collapses during baking

Tags: baking, eggs, souffle

I am trying to make a cheese soufflé to surprise my girlfriend on her birthday (24 Jan). After several cooking trials, I still face a key problem: my soufflé collapsed after baking for 25-30 minutes.

What did I do wrong? Here are the steps to the recipe;

- boil equipment
- grease butter to the renakin, place into the freezer
- separate egg whites (no yolk mixed)
- add a little salt to egg whites
- add a little sugar to egg whites
- using a hand mixer, whip the egg whites adding more sugar during whip
- melt 40g butter (100C)
- Whisk 40g all purpose flour into melted butter
- pour 250g milk slowly and whisk util it mixed
- wait until it cools down
- re-grease butter to the renakin, place into the freezer
- beat the egg yolks to a creamy consistency, then pour into the milk mixture
- add 1/3 of the mixture to the base, continue to add the whites folding very gently.
- Preheat oven to 200C (5-10 minutes)
- pour the mixture into the renakin
- add the cheese on the top
- bake at 170'C (with heat select="lower")

After about 25-30 minutes and a 2cm rise, the soufflé collapses prior to removing from oven.

---

updated 19 Jan Evening :

I do

- buy better hand mixer
- use more flour (50g)
- move egg whites whipping process to last steps
- reduce whipping time to 5 minutes
- bake with heat select="lower" about 15min after that change to "upper and lower"
- sit in front of oven and see the soufflé every moment.

result:

- at 20mins: the soufflé raise about 3.5 to 4cm (from 5cm height renakin)
- around 25mins: it collapse about 0.5cm, so I immediately remove it from oven (T-T)
- after than it collapse very fast. (I guess it is common)

Thank you very much @jefromi and @KatieK for your comments and links. I plan to buy oven thermometer this morning because I have no it yet.

---

updated 21 Jan Lunch :

Yesterday I found problem on the oven temperature. When I set temperature to 170 C, real temperature is 150C or below (because it keep going down). So today I try to keep in range of 160-200C and no collapses now.

Thanks you very much to everybody again for kindly help.

[image: my souffle]

Comment: Soufflés are about more than ingredient lists - posting the entire recipe might be helpful. When you say it collapsed after baking 25-30 minutes, do you mean that it rose while baking, then collapsed at that point? Or after you removed it from the oven?

Comment: it rise about 2 cm and it collapsed before removed from oven.

Comment: A couple related questions: http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/10177/collapsing-souffle and http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/6295/could-you-describe-the-souffle-technique

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two likely causes of soufflé problems.

1) **Egg foam**. Be sure that you're whipping them to peaks (soft peaks, as I recall) when you first whip them.  Then, when adding the 2 mixtures together in 3rds, be sure that you're properly [folding](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/4589/what-does-it-mean-to-fold-in-an-ingredient-into-a-mix) in the whites; this is a very specific technique, and easy to over-do.

2) **Oven heat**.  Use an oven thermometer to check your oven's temp - it's probably wrong.  Put some extra mass in that oven (like a baking stone or brick) to reduce wild temperature swings during baking.

But, as in the linked questions in the comments, all soufflés fall to some degree.

Comment: Thanks very much for comments and links. It is great video. I have no the thermometer yet so I will buy it today.